# What performace impovements it has in case AMPHP get executed besides nginx

Tags: nginx, amphp

cool project.
one Question. Does it make sense to use it within php-fpm instance that takes request over nginx's fastcgi.

best.

Comment: It depends. If you need to execute some I/O tasks in parallel, sure.

Answer (score 0):

That depends highly on what you're doing. If you can leverage it for concurrent I/O within the same request, you probably will be able to see improvements with using Amp or any other event loop + concurrent non-blocking I/O.

In case you're not aware, there's also a [standalone application server called Aerys](https://github.com/amphp/aerys). If every I/O operation you do is non-blocking, you might benefit even more. Aerys runs by default with the number of workers corresponding to the number of CPU cores available. You won't have many worker threads with rather expensive context switches and no overhead from multiple worker processes.